# jquery posting to php file

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Trying to get some jquery code to post a value to a php file I have, and return an array of data.

The basic idea is to search a database, then fill bootstrap's typeahead with the value. Working in CodeIgniter.

Search controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Search extends CI_Controller {


 public function index()
 {

 }

 public function getSearchResults() 
 {

  $partialSearch = $_POST['partialSearch'];
  if (strlen($partialSearch) > 5) {
  $this->db->select('mobile_number');
  $this->db->like('mobile_number', $partialSearch); 
  $query = $this->db->get('phone_lines');

  $result = $query->result();
  $data = "";
  foreach($result as $row){
     $data = $data . "<div>" . $row->mobile_number . "</div>";
  }
  echo $data; 
  }

 }
}
```

jquery that currently fills the typeahead:

```
<script>
        //searches the database for mobile numbers
        $(function() {
        var searchItem = $("#typeahead").val();
        var itemsArray = [
                "1111111111",
                "2222222222",
                "3333333333"
                ];
        //push to search controller, receive back array of mobile numbers that match

            $("#typeahead").typeahead({

                source: itemsArray
            });
        });
    </script>
```

So, I'm not sure how to post the value of the search box to the php, then how to format it properly when it is returned. Any thoughts? Pretty new to all of this. Not even sure it is possible. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try your luck with the [docs site](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) first?

Comment: i think we need to put a question up on meta to make the search box 300% larger.

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax`, `$.post` and `$.getjson` are some of the many jQuery functions out there.